# spawn two apps in split view from terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, automation, window-manager

I often use a local code editor and `latexmk` to get a UX similar to the Overleaf web-based LaTeX editor. To do this, I:

1. navigate to the project directory in terminal.
2. spawn a text editor in a GUI window: `gvim file.tex`.
3. run `latexmk -pvc -pdf file.tex`, which itself will:

   a) spawn a PDF viewer for `file.pdf`, and

   b) block the terminal infinitely to poll for changes in `file.tex` and recompile.
4. use the mouse to initiate split-view fullscreen on the editor.
5. select the PDF viewer as the other window.

It would be great to automate this entire process. Naturally I can do steps 2-3 with a shell script. But how do I automate steps 4-5? I'm also fine with using Python (preferred), AppleScript, or some other scripting language.